# React: Why correct practice to receive api response via props?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I read that your component should receive your API response via props (mapStateToProps) which before it arrives to your component is handled by a reducer.

My problem is that those props are not cleared - screwing with my state and render.

Example: I receive a validation error message "validationErrorMsg" which I set my state to, and render that state. When the user fires off another validation call I reset the state, but while the call is in flight the state gets populated AGAIN with the props which contains the old validationErrorMsg which updates the state again incorrectly.

What I've done to solve this is to dispatch 2 events on my api responses. One with the response and another to clear the response - that why clearing the property so that the next in flight call does not get dirty data.

So my question is, am I doing it incorrectly or should API responses not come via the props system?

```
validate() {
  const { validateApiCall, formValues } = this.props;

  let serial = formValues.serial;

  this.setState({    
    validationError: undefined
  });

  validateApiCall({serialred});
}
```

This function below gets called on keypresses, other events, etc. I have just reset my state, but this will set my state again with old data (via  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) yes I know to be deprecated)

```
function mapStateToProps( { upgrades} ) {
  let props = {
     propValidationError: (upgrades && upgrades.validationError ? upgrades.validationError : undefined)
  };
return props;
```

}

Damnit now I have the old stuff back again.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.propValidationError) {
   this.setState({validationError: nextProps.tradeinValidationError});
  }
}
```

My current fix for it (feels like a hack because of a bad framework). I clear the props by dispatching another event which will clear the prop.

```
try {
  const res = await axios.post(url, {formValues});
  dispatch({ type: FETCH_UPGRADES_TRADEIN_VALIDATE_DEVICE, payload: res.data });
  } catch (e) {
    const { data, status } = e.response;
    if (status >= 400 && status < 500) {
      dispatch({type: FETCH_UPGRADES_TRADEIN_VALIDATE_ERROR_RESPONSE, tradeinValidationError: data.message});
      dispatch({type: FETCH_UPGRADES_TRADEIN_VALIDATE_ERROR_RESPONSE_DONE, tradeinValidationError: data.message});
    }
```

Comment: validate in yup, receive some props from redux, set validation of yup using this props

Answer (score 2):

When the user fires off another validation call, and the behaviour you want is that the old validationErrorMsg is not shown anymore, then that means that the old error message should be removed from the app's state at the moment the user fires off another validation call.

It is completely irrelevant *where* that state is stored -- a component's state, Contex, Redux, whatever.

If you use Redux and that is where the error messages are stored (perfectly OK choice), then you need to make sure that the action that fires off another validation call also removes the old error message.

Or alternatively, have a flag like 'isFetching' or so that gets set to true, and let the component not show error messages when that flag is true, but instead some spinner.

Anyway, all this same logic needs to happen regardless of where you keep the state.

Comment: "then that means that the old error message should be removed from the app's state at the moment the user fires off another validation cal" As I said I do this: this.setState({tradeinValidationError: undefined}); but then mapStateToProps fires off again polluting (setting) my state with old data (because its impossble to clear a value from props). "Or alternatively, have a flag like 'isFetching' " yes that is the other option - so basically a work around as I did - begs the question is the framework bad?

Comment: @JacquesKoorts: that means you have the same state both in Redux and in the component's state. Don't do that, pick one.

Comment: I'm happy to choose the Redux one, but how do I clear a property in redux?

Comment: @JacquesKoorts: one final remark: it's also perfectly legitimate to do without Redux. The problems Redux tries to solve usually only show up in larger applications, and introducing it leads to extra complexity (as you've found). So it might be better to just use normal state for everything instead.

Answer (score 0):

API responses should come via props.

If you are firing the next validation you could reset the values in store/parent component (not sure how you pass those props) to not pass the same props again.

Can you share some example code how you handle that?

Comment: I do reset, but then mapStateToProps sets it all back (you cannot clear a single prop programmably) to the old stuff. Sample code attached

Comment: From which source your component gets the props? You need to reset those props there. So if you are passing that from parent component you should update it there. If you get it from the store then you should reset the store before calling again the api.

Comment: No parent component. I get it from dispatch events (from a reducer). I don't know where this props gets stored or how to clear them. As I understand you can't clear props.

Comment: @JacquesKoorts: but you can dispatch an action and let the reducer remove that state from the Redux state, so that they are cleared from the props.

Comment: Just like @RemcoGerlich proposed.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich that is what I did. It just seems a bit stupid way of working. I've updated my sample to show you. Is this what we're suppose to do? Seems like a hack. FETCH_UPGRADES_TRADEIN_VALIDATE_ERROR_RESPONSE_DONE does the clearing of the prop. So if this is the correct why all our API calls should have this reset stuff? Backend code does not look like this. Why reset data? I see other ppl just does the fetch() in component and assign state. that way you don't have to do this double entries all over.

Comment: I would 1) Not have any component state at all, that's what Redux is for. 2) Not put any of this logic in a component, but in an async action creator. 3) Use one action when you send the request to put the state in the situation you want it to be while a request is being sent, and another action for when the response is received. Sending two actions at the same time looks very strange to me, why not let the first action have the same effect as you do know with two actions?

Comment: @JacquesKoorts Especially calling setState from componentWillReceiveProps looks just wrong, you always get double updates that and should never be necessary.

Comment: @JacquesKoorts: you don't need to have validationError in component state, it's already in a prop.

Comment: @MaciejTrojniarz: apologies for sending so many comments to your answer, I thought I was typing under mine, oops.

Comment: Thanks Remoco, I'll have a read on how to implement those points.